# YAMLToJSON: variable substitution failed: missing closing brace

Tags: yaml, kubernetes-helm, nexus3, fluxcd

I'm trying to inject few jetty variables from fluxcd HelmRelease into heom chart, However yaml or fluxcd refers to a variable instead of considering the value as a string.

```
apiVersion: helm.toolkit.fluxcd.io/v2beta1
kind: HelmRelease
metadata:
  name: test12
spec:
  releaseName: test12
  chart:
    spec:
      chart: test12
      version: "1.0.0"
      sourceRef:
        kind: test
        name: test
        namespace: sources
  interval: 1m
    remediation:
      retries: 2
  timeout: 10m
  values:
    properties:
    - nexus-args=${jetty.etc}/jetty.xml,${jetty.etc}/jetty-http.xml,${jetty.etc}/jetty-https.xml,${jetty.etc}/jetty-http-redirect-to-https.xml,${jetty.etc}/jetty-requestlog.xml
    - nexus-context-path=/
```

Seeing below error while applying the above file `var substitution failed for 'nexus': YAMLToJSON: variable substitution failed: missing closing brace` I tried using  double quotes and single quotes for nexus-args but didn't help much

How can I make yaml or flux consider `${jetty.etc}/jetty.xml,${jetty.etc}/jetty-http.xml,${jetty.etc}/jetty-https.xml,${jetty.etc}/jetty-http-redirect-to-https.xml,${jetty.etc}/jetty-requestlog.xml` as a string instead of variable reference